# VS 2012 Plugin to make working with Classic ASP Easier

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp-classic

I am currently working with a Classic ASP project that grabs some data from the database, creates a bunch of HTML and embeds the data into it, then emails that to people.

I want to know where this HTML body is being generated (company wants to make a change to it), the files involved are numerous and have hundreds of includes .. is there a way I can easily determine the location of the emailing code?

> Ctrl + Shift + F

Does not work because that HTML is shared among many pages, and none of them match the Source Code in the Email I am getting. Could this be because Outlook 2010 adds extra Markup?

Are there any VS 2012 plugins that make working with Classic ASP easier and aid me solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug classic ASP inside Visual Studio.  Go to the DEBUG menu in VS, click on "Attach to Process", and select the w3wp.exe process.    If there is more than one, you should be able to determine which is which by the "user name" column.

Once you're attached, go ahead and set breakpoints and watches and you can step through your code to see where it goes.